# batched version of roll in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing a batched version of `tf.roll`, where each sample `x[i]` in a batch `x` is shifted by an individual amount `shifts[i]` along the last axis.
For example, let

```
shifts = tf.constant([3,2,1,0,-1])
x = tf.repeat(tf.range(5)[None], repeats=shifts.shape[0], axis=0)
print(x)
# [[0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]]
```

then the intended output of a batched roll of `x` with shifts `shifts` would be

```
 [[2 3 4 0 1]
  [3 4 0 1 2]
  [4 0 1 2 3]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 4 0]]
```

Using `tf.vectorized_map` and `tf.roll` yields the following unexpected behaviour (in `tensorflow 2.9.2` and `2.10`):

```
y = tf.vectorized_map(
    lambda x: tf.roll(x[0], shift=x[1], axis=-1),
    elems=[x, shifts],
)
print(y)
# [[3 4 0 1 2]
#  [4 0 1 2 3]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [1 2 3 4 0]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]]
```

Replacing `tf.vectorized_map` by `tf.map_fn`, yields the intended output:

```
y1 = tf.map_fn(
    lambda x: tf.roll(x[0], shift=x[1], axis=-1),
    elems=[x, shifts],
    fn_output_signature=x.dtype
)
print(y1)
# [[2 3 4 0 1]
#  [3 4 0 1 2]
#  [4 0 1 2 3]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [1 2 3 4 0]]
```

Furthermore, modifying the `fn` argument in `tf.vectorized_map` (as a sanity check), gives the expected output:

```
y2 = tf.vectorized_map(
    lambda x: x[0]+x[1],
    elems=[x, shifts],
)
print(y2)
# [[ 3  4  5  6  7]
#  [ 2  3  4  5  6]
#  [ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 0  1  2  3  4]
#  [-1  0  1  2  3]]
```

Hence, it seems that `tf.vectorized_map` behaves unexpectedly in combination with `tf.roll`.

**Question 1**: What is the reason for this unexpected behaviour when `tf.vectorized_map` is used with `tf.roll`?

**Question 2**: What is the recommended implementation of a batched version of `tf.roll`?

Answer (score 1):

You need `axis = 0`. I am unsure as to why. Maybe vectorized_map shapes the data differently at dispatch than map_fn, which throws the code off? I don't know. See below. Note that I renamed `x` to `input_x`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

shifts = tf.constant([3,2,1,0,-1])
input_x = tf.repeat(tf.range(5)[None], repeats=shifts.shape[0], axis=0)

y = tf.vectorized_map(
    lambda x: tf.roll(x[0], shift=x[1], axis=-1),
    elems=[input_x, shifts],
)
print(y)

y1 = tf.map_fn(
    lambda x: tf.roll(x[0], shift=x[1], axis=-1),
    elems=[input_x, shifts],
    fn_output_signature=input_x.dtype
)
print(y1)

y2 = tf.vectorized_map(
    lambda x: tf.roll(x[0], shift=x[1], axis=0),
    elems=[input_x, shifts],
)
print(y2)

y3 = tf.map_fn(
    lambda x: tf.roll(x[0], shift=x[1], axis=0),
    elems=[input_x, shifts],
    fn_output_signature=input_x.dtype
)
print(y3)
```